# Why after typeof x === "string" there is no narrowing to string, but instead T & string

Tags: typescript

Using the function type example from this link - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

I don't understand why type narrowing does not occur in this case, and return typing does not work without using:

```
as NameOrId<T>;
```

How in this case it is possible to write the given example more competently?

Example:

```
interface IdLabel {
  id: number;
}

interface NameLabel {
  name: string;
}

type NameOrId<T extends number | string> = T extends string ? NameLabel : IdLabel;

const createLabel2 = <T extends number | string>(nameOrId: T): NameOrId<T> => {
  if (typeof nameOrId === "string") {
    const result = {
      // why in this case type nameOrId
      // is (parameter) nameOrId: T & string
      // instead of symple string ??
      name: nameOrId,
    } 
    return result;
  }
  return {
    id: 123,
  } as NameOrId<T>;
};
```

Comment: `T extends number | string` doesn't exactly mean that `T` is exactly `number | string`, but a subset of them, which also includes `never` ( empty set). Thus the best the compiler can get is just by intersecting the `T` with `string`, since it doesn't know the exact type. Does this explain the problem? Should I write the answer?

Comment: @wonderflame yes, should write. I dont understand, why can be 'never' if I write 'number' of 'string'.

Comment: Sure, will explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the mathematical sets theory. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20set%20A%20is,inclusion%20(or%20sometimes%20containment).):

> In mathematics, set `A` is a **subset** of a set `B` if all elements of `A` are also elements of `B`; `B` is then a **superset** of `A`. It is possible for `A` and `B` to be equal; if they are unequal, then `A` is a proper **subset** of `B`. The relationship of one set being a **subset** of another is called **inclusion** (or sometimes **containment**). The empty set is also a subset of any set.

The typescript uses the same logic for unions, intersections, and assignments.

For example, the `any` is a **superset** of every possible type, which means that every primitive, complex, custom types that we create are **subset** of the `any`.

Another example is number literals, suppose that `number` is actually `[-Infinity, +Infinity]`, which includes every number and we have `type A = 1`. Since, `number` includes every element of the `A`, `A` is a subset of `number` and that's why we are able to do the following:

```
let num: number = 1
```

The same goes for the string literals. `string` contains every possible string, but literal like `type B = 'str'` only has one potential value.

In short, you are able to assign to a variable typed with `A` any other values that have a type of subset of `A`.

When you deal with the non-primitive types, for example, objects, the superset is the type that is less specific:

```
type Superset = {a: string}
type Subset = {a: string; b: string}
```

The empty set in the typescript is `never`, and since the empty set is the subset of any type it is fully valid to do the following:

```
const a: number = {} as never;
```

Now, in generics `A extends B` means that `A` is the subset `B`, not that `A` is equal to `B`, thus the compiler is unable to determine the exact type for the generic argument and the best it can do when you check against a type guard is to intersect it.

More about the set theory in typescript in this [blog](https://blog.thoughtspile.tech/2023/01/23/typescript-sets/)

Comment: I dont understand, why this is all work: function createLabel(id: number): IdLabel;
function createLabel(name: string): NameLabel;
function createLabel(nameOrId: string | number): IdLabel | NameLabel;
function createLabel(nameOrId: string | number): IdLabel | NameLabel {
  if (typeof nameOrId === "string") {
    return {
      name: nameOrId,
    };
  }
  return {
    id: nameOrId,
  };
}. In this example TS understant, that  return {
      name: nameOrId,
    }; , nameOrId is string, but in my question dont understand.

Comment: because you are expecting a number, not something that extends number

Comment: I dont understand. I see that is two clone type and function, but in example on top it is work, but in question dont work.

Comment: In the question, you have a generic argument that extends a number. In this example you accept a number directly

Comment: I thought it was the same

Comment: I rewrite my example which on top an it is work: type NameOrId<T extends (number | string)> = T extends string ? NameLabel : IdLabel;

const createLabel2 = (nameOrId: number | string): NameOrId<number | string> => {
  if (typeof nameOrId === "string") {
    const result = {
      name: nameOrId,
    } 
    return result;
  }
  return {
    id: 123,
  } 
};